# Is better to use a single smart contract or one for each bet?

Tags: contract-design

Let's suppose I want to create a Virtual Coin in a "bet on everithing" ecosystem. An use can bet some coin on some events, some other user can counter bet, a mechanism for solve the bet suppose it is in place. My question is ( really newbie here ), should I create a smart contract just for the coin in this ecosystem, and each bet should I deploy a new contract, or can each bet and counterbet, resolution mechanism etc be in a single smart contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advantages of multiple contracts:

- Each new contract gets a new address. This can be useful if you want to allow directly sending Ether to a contract address without calling a function.
- The separate addresses can be useful to have a better overview. The users can watch only the contract they're interested in inside their wallet, or on websites like etherscan.io. (this advantage partially goes away if you're going to develop your own user interface)

Disadvantages of multiple contracts:

- Deploying a contract has a fairly high gas cost of `32000`.
- Reading and writing from one contract to another contract carries extra gas cost.
- It is usually easier to program with only one contract.

**Conclusion:**

To lower both transaction fee and software complexity you should strive to use only one contract.

In my opinion you should only use multiple contracts when it is necessary, or when it is very convenient.

Comment: There's another disadvantage that's frequently missed I think. For want of a better word, I would call it "cost to the community". Ethereum nodes hold their data forever. I'm not saying separate contracts is more space intensive than a single contract with more data (necessarily--there's probably de-dupping in the node), but it should be a consideration. Forever is a really long time, and what if everyone did that?

Comment: @ThomasJayRush I'm pretty certain the increase of hard drive storage capacity will be able to keep up with the exponential growth of the Ethereum blockchain while it is in its growing phase. The transaction fee is a fee you pay the miners to store your data forever. The gas price market determines the price of storing data forever. I think we can just let the market do its job of efficiently allocating resources. If the blockchain size ever becomes a problem, the transaction fees for storing data will go up and people will be economically incentivized not to store too much.

Comment: I run a full archive node with tracing enabled. The Parity chain takes up 370 GB. And it’s grown 27 gig since Byzantium. Hard drive space on non-full nodes can keep up, that’s true, but not full nodes. The concern here, in my opinion, is a serious centralization risk, if few and increasingly fewer full archive nodes run because people use hard drive space at a clip of 20 GB every two or three weeks (for a full node), a small number of big companies with mega hard drives will eventually hold all the data.